# Change Related Lists Link

Tags: related-list

I created a custom object which is related to accounts by a master-detail relation. In the related list on accounts details page I can edit and view a record (like with every related list).

[image]

When I view the record by clicking its name, on the record detail page there is no link or button which returns to the account page. There is only the link "Back to List: Custom Object Definitions", it calls the object definition in setup.

[image]

I think this doesn't make sense for our users. When I view the related record, I want to go back to its account and not to setup.

Is there a way to change or remove the setup link? Or can I disable the record name link in the related list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard behaviour. And it normally displayed the recently visited link in case you want to go back.

In standard page layout I don't think that would be possible. But on child detail page Parent account record is a clickable link. So your user can click that to go back to parent detail page.

Also if you remove the name field from your related list then user can not be able to go there from Account detail page. Although Edit and delete link will still be available for them.